# Reading private enums that are stored in a multimap as value

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, multimap

I have some trouble accessing and printing the value of an enum class, that is stored inside a multimap, as a value. The error I'm getting is:

> error C2228: left of '.getFileType' must have class/struct/union

From what I understand, my pointer is pointing at the enum class and it can't access the getFileType(); function.

Can I do something to access and read the value of the enum (so I can print it out on the console)? My multimap pair must be like the one I did .

Any suggestions are well appreciated, since I really can't work this out with my head.

Thanks for your time!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

fstream fp;

class CFile {
    string m_strFile;
    unsigned int m_size;
public:
    CFile () { m_strFile = ""; m_size = 0; }
    CFile (string name, int size ) { m_strFile = name; m_size = size; }
    string getFileName () const { return m_strFile; }
    int getFileSize () const { return m_size; }
    void setFileSize ( int size ) { m_size = size; }
    bool operator< (CFile& obj) {
        return ( m_size < obj.m_size );
    }
    bool operator== (const CFile& obj) {
        return ( m_size == obj.m_size );
    }
    friend ostream& operator<< ( ostream& ost, const CFile& obj ) {
        return ost << obj.m_strFile << obj.m_size;
    }
    friend istream& operator>> ( istream& ist, CFile& obj ) {
        return ist >> obj.m_strFile >> obj.m_size;
    }
    static bool Greater(const CFile& obj1, const CFile& obj2) {
        if ( obj1.m_size > obj2.m_size )
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
};

bool operator< (CFile obj1, CFile obj2) {
    return obj1.getFileName()<obj2.getFileName();
}

class CDirectory {
    string m_strDirectory;
    enum class Filetype {
        Archive, Hidden, ReadOnly, System, FileNotSupported
    };
    Filetype filetype;
    multimap <CFile, Filetype> m_DirectoryMap;
public:
    Filetype getFileType();
    CDirectory (string n) {
              fp.open (n, ios::in);
              string dirName, fileName,  fType;
              int fileSize;
              fp >> dirName;
              m_strDirectory = dirName;
              if (fType == "Archive")
                  filetype = Filetype::Archive;
              else if (fType == "Hidden")
                  filetype = Filetype::Hidden;
              else if (fType == "ReadOnly")
                  filetype = Filetype::ReadOnly;
              else if (fType == "System")
                  filetype = Filetype::System;
              else 
                  filetype = Filetype::FileNotSupported;
              while (fp >> fileName >> fileSize >> fType) {
                      CFile obj (fileName, fileSize);
                      m_DirectoryMap.insert(pair<CFile, Filetype>(CFile(obj.getFileName(), obj.getFileSize()), Filetype(filetype)));
              }
              multimap<CFile, Filetype>::iterator p = m_DirectoryMap.begin();
              while ( p != m_DirectoryMap.end()) {
                cout << endl << p->first.getFileName() << '\t' << p->first.getFileName() << '\t' << p->second.getFileType() << endl; // im getting the error here, at p->second.getFileType()
              }
    }
    string getDirectory () { return m_strDirectory; }
};

CDirectory::Filetype CDirectory::getFileType() {
        return filetype;
}

int main () {
    CDirectory obj("test.txt");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? Can you please mark it out in the source with a comment?

Comment: Done. I'm getting it at the ` cout << endl << p->first.getFileName() << '\t' << p->first.getFileName() << '\t' << p->second.getFileType() << endl;`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you right, but do you want to print out the enumeration value? Do you want to print it as a string? Or as its numerical value?

Comment: Yes, I want to print out the value of the enum, but as a string (aka - 'Archive'. 'ReadOnly' etc.). I did p->second, as you suggested and I had to overload an << operator, to be able to print it out, but it prints out the numerical value of the enum. :) What should I do to get the string value?

Comment: An unrelated note about your file-type design: It doesn't really makes sense as those types are not mutually exclusive. A file can by a hidden, read-only system archive file for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print out the value of `p->second` there are basically two different solutions, depending on what you actually want to be printed.

If you want to print the *numerical* value of the enumeration you can use `static_cast`, e.g.

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(p->second);
```

If you want to print a string or some other representation of the enumeration, you need to overload the "output" operator `<<`. Perhaps something like this

```
class CDirectory {
    ...

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, FileType const type)
    {
        static std::map<FileType, std::string> const types = {
            { FileType::Archive, "archive" },
            { FileType::Hidden, "hidden" },
            { FileType::ReadOnly, "read-only" },
            { FileType::System, "system" },
            { FileType::FileNotSupported, "not-supported" }
        };
        return os << types[type];
    }

    ...
};
```

Then you can simply do

```
std::cout << p->second;
```

---

Using `switch` instead of a map:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, FileType const type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    case FileType::Archive:
        os << "archive";
        break;
    case FileType::Hidden:
        os << "hidden";
        break;
    case FileType::ReadOnly
        os << "read-only";
        break;
    case FileType::System
        os << "system";
        break;
    case FileType::FileNotSupported
        os << "not-supported";
        break;
    }

    return os;
}
```

Comment: @hopittyhop The stream must be passed by reference not by value, updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, I saw it now. After editing it a bit, because my FileType is without capital T and putting curly brackets at the beginning of the function I still get an initialization error `error C2552: 'types' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list` :( Any idea on this?

Comment: @hopittyhop Ah, it seems you don't have C++11 enabled (or to old compiler so it's not supported), then your only choice is to use the `switch` version. I'll edit the answer to put it back.

Comment: There is also https://github.com/aantron/better-enums for reading enums from and writing to string, if you're willing to use a library. Disclaimer, I am the author.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I'm using Visual Studio 2012, I thought C++11 is enabled by default on it or am I wrong?

Comment: It works using the switch statement!!! Thank you!! But I do have a new problem.. all my files are printed as 'not-supported' on the console :D In my test file I got 5 lines: every line contains for example : File1(fileName) 1000(fileSize) Archive(fileType) , guess I have to work on why am I getting every file as 'not-supported' now.

Comment: Oh, nevermind... I had to put my if-else (for the enum check), inside the while, where I iterate on my multimap :) Silly me. Thanks for your help @Joachim Pileborg!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
p->second.getFileType()
```

The map being accessed here appears to be:

```
multimap <CFile, Filetype> m_DirectoryMap;
```

The second component in the map is `Filetype`, which is an enum [POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c). It is not some kind of a class or a function that implements the `()` operator.

Comment: hopittyhop isn't calling the `operator()`, though. They're calling `getFileType()` member function. Otherwise the answer applies.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I understand, my pointer is pointing at the enum class and it can't access the getFileType(); function.

It's not a pointer. It's an iterator. But yes, the error indeed does state that you cannot access `getFileType` member function. Your enum has no such member function and in fact, enums cannot have member functions.

> Can I do something to access and read the value of the enum

Yes. In the case of your iterator, the value is in `p->second`.

> (so I can print it out on the console)

You'll need to define an overload for `operator<<(std::ostream, const FileType&)` in order to pass the value to a stream.